# How to write $\frac{x^3+4x}{x^2-4}$ as a serie at $x_0=1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I did this, but what to do next?

$f(x)=x+\frac{4}{x-2}+\frac{4}{x+2}$

Comment: You write each of the three terms as a series around $x_0 = 1$. For instance, we have $x = 1 + (x-1)$. The two fractions have a bit more than two terms, but it should be doable. Lastly, just add the three series together, term by term.

Comment: Simply expand each term in the decomposition $$f(x)=1+(x-1)-\frac4{1-(x-1)}+\frac4{3(1+\frac13(x-1))}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case the $n$-th derivative of $f$ is explicitly calculable:
$$f(x) = x + 4\,\frac{1}{x - 2} + 4\,\frac{1}{x + 2}$$
$$f'(x) = 1 - 4\,\frac{1}{(x - 2)^2} - 4\,\frac{1}{(x + 2)^2}$$
$$f''(x) =  4\,\frac{2}{(x - 2)^3} + 4\,\frac{2}{(x + 2)^3}$$
$$\cdots$$
$$f^{(n)}(x) =  (-1)^n4\,\frac{n!}{(x - 2)^{n+1}} + (-1)^n4\,\frac{n!}{(x + 2)^{n+1}}$$
Now, you can apply Taylor's theorem.

Comment: Do you mean like this: $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (x-x_0)^n 4 n! (-1)^n \left[\frac{1}{(x_0-2)^{n+1}}+\frac{1}{(x_0+2)^{n+1}}\right] $

Comment: @AnaMatijanovic, without the $n!$ plus $x = x_0 + (x - x_0)$.

Comment: Why there is no $n!$?

Comment: @AnaMatijanovic, because the $1/n!$ in the Taylor's formula.

Comment: So the complete solution at $x_0=1$ is: $f(x)=x+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} 4(-1)^n(\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}-\frac{1}{(-1)^n}  ) x^n$

Comment: @AnaMatijanovic, $\cdots(x - 1)^n$.